# Swift 2 Introspection

Tags: swift, generics, swift2, introspection

I am converting some "old" Swift code to Swift 2.0, and I run into an error I cannot get rid of. 
My function receives an Array of a type (whatever), and returns a new Array of the same type.
This code no longer works in Swift 2.0:

```
func makePattern1<T>(var list: Array<T>) -> Array<T> {
    let theType = list.dynamicType
    var result = theType()
    for i in 1..<list.count {
        result.append(list[i])
        result.append(list[i-1])
    }
    return result
}
```

giving the error message: "Initializing from a metatype  value must reference 'init' explicitly".
Correcting the code with:
`var result = theType.init()`
gives a "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error.
What am I missing?

Comment: Is there a reason for you to do this? Looks like what you want can be accomplished much easier with `map`.

Comment: Also, what stops you from just saying `var result = Array<T>()`?

Comment: `var result = Array<T>()` works fine, thanks.

Comment: Could you give an example with `map`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is written in Swift 2.1 and does use the `map` function as you requested in the comments.

```
func makePattern1<T>(list: [T]) -> [T] {
    return list[0..<list.count-1]
        .enumerate()
        .map { [list[$0.index+1], list[$0.index]] }
        .flatten()
        .map { $0 as T }
}
```

### Update #1

*(thanks Martin R)*

```
func makePattern1<T>(list: [T]) -> [T] {
    return list[0..<list.count-1]
        .enumerate()
        .flatMap { [list[$0.index+1], list[$0.index]] }
}
```

### Update #2

```
func makePattern1<T>(list: [T]) -> [T] {
    return [Int](1..<list.count).flatMap { [list[$0], list[$0-1]] }
}
```

### Test

```
makePattern1([1,2,3,4,5]) // > [2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4]
```

Comment: `.map` + `flatten` can be combined to `flatMap`, and then you can also remove  the final "artificial" `.map { $0 as T }`

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun: An alternative solution:

```
func makePattern2<T>(list: [T]) -> [T] {
     return zip(list.dropFirst(), list).flatMap { [$0, $1] }
}

let m = makePattern2([1,2,3,4,5])
print(m) // [2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4]
```

Remarks:

- `list.dropFirst()` is a sequence of all but the first array elements.
- `zip(list.dropFirst(), list)` is then a sequence of 
  `(list[$0.i+1], list[$0.i])` tuples.
- `flatMap { [$0, $1] }` combines these tuples to a single array again.

Comment: Very nice. The closure of this `flatMap` does only use the params of the closure itself. This is a pure functional solution.